# BASS "Play" a stream

Tags: c++, audio, stream, bass

Hello friends developers,

I have a question, I am doing a shooting game, but I'm not sure how to implement when an explosion happens, because the explosion is always the same sound over and can occur in a short time, ie, the sound is not even ending and another explosion happens. My question is, how to "play" more than once in the same stream?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very simple example:

```
int device = -1; // Default Sounddevice
int freq = 44100; // Sample rate (Hz)
HSTREAM streamHandle; // Handle for open stream


/* Initialize output device */
BASS_Init(device, freq, 0, 0, NULL);


/* Load your soundfile and play it */
streamHandle = BASS_StreamCreateFile(FALSE, "your_file.mp3", 0, 0, 0);
BASS_ChannelPlay(streamHandle, FALSE);


/* As very last, close Bass */
BASS_Free();
```

While this example plays your soundfile only once, you can create a new handle each time you need the sound.
But `BASS_Init()` and `BASS_Free()` have to run only once.

Another solution is to play the sound as a sample:

```
HSAMPLE streamHandle; // Handle for sample
HCHANNEL channel; // Handle for open channel of the sample


/* Initialize output device */
BASS_Init(device, freq, 0, 0, NULL);


/* Load sample and play it */
streamHandle = BASS_SampleLoad(FALSE, "your_file.mp3", 0, 0, 0);
channel = BASS_SampleGetChannel(streamHandle, FALSE);


/* Once you are done with your sample you should free it */
BASS_SampleFree(streamHandle);

/* As very last, close Bass */
BASS_Free();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we're talking about the same [Bass Audio API](http://www.un4seen.com/doc/), then navigate to the online documention for `BASS\Channels\Bass_ChannelPlay()`. Call `Bass_ChannelPlay()` passing your existing handle for the explosion and setting `restart` to `true` - see the documentation for more information.